# how to resolve scunthorpe situations in squid?

Tags: linux, windows, proxy, squid, bypass

how can i configure my squ-id to resolve [scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) ,

**Problem in breif** :

i work on a small it firm where we have blocked adult websites using squid,recently i got a problem that i cant access the sites which contain good content for e.g i cant access profile of thomas in sir of dmz

[image]

This is the one example where we cant access some good site and profile,journeyman geek defined this problem as [scunthorpe problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22659713#22659713) so my questions were :

how can I effectively configure squid for providing access to this kind of urls

Configuration :

Server : redhat linux 5

client : Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very, very simple. There is one 100% reliable solution to the scunthorpe problem, and sooner or later, it's the one everyone settles on. Don't filter in ways that are vulnerable to the scunthorpe problem. Just don't do it.

For example, if "ABC" is a bad word you want to prohibit, prohibit "ABC", not "AABC", not "ABCC", but "ABC".

But even then, you probably still shouldn't do it. Blocking on the word "porn" will block scientific articles on the effect of exposure to pornography. Blocking on the word "bitch" will block articles on breeding dogs. Filtering based on keywords is just not particularly good.